# How can I search channel entries based on related entries, when search:field_name= doesn't apply to those fields?

Tags: search

I want to display all entries from a specific channel that has a specific related entry tied to it. But `search:field_name=` doesn't apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using the query module instead of the channels module? I've done a lot of fancy stuff. You could also try dynamic parameters instead of search.

CreateSean's response is a good way to go through it as well :)

Comment: Yeah. This was the route I took ultimately. Though Sean's answer certainly works too.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like using Pixel & Tonic's Playa module might be your best bet. It has tags for pulling entries based on relationships.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach it this way, though I haven't tested this.

I would list out the entry that everything is related to by using the entry_id paramater and then within that entry use [Reverse Related Entries](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/relationships.html#reverse-related-entries-tag-pair). The code sample in the docs linked should get you there.